# How to get params in react hooks component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

For class component there is "this.props.route.params" option. How to get params from one screen to other screen in react hook functional component.

```
"react": "16.11.0",
"react-native": "0.62.2",
"react-navigation": "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.2",
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically navigate using react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the hook `useRouter` from `@react-navigation/native`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';

function MyText() {
  const route = useRoute();

  return <Text>{route.params.caption}</Text>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

If the component is in a navigation stack use:

```js
const myParam = props.route.params?.param_name
```

Otherwise:

```js
import { useRoute } from "@react-navigation/native";
//
//
const route = useRoute()

const myParam = route.params?.param_name
```

The `?` is for security. If `params` is undefined it won't crash.

Comment: OP did specify hooks in the question

Answer (score -1):

this.props.navigation.getParam('param_name')

Comment: OP did specify hooks in the question